# Не создается папка "allure-results" в проекте Allure2+JUnit+Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, allure

Всем привет!
Не первый день бьюсь с проблемой, надеялся решить силами уже заданных вопросов, но не получилось.. Состоит она в следующем: попытка подключить allure репорт в проект не увенчалась успехом. Я попробовал различные варианты написания pom.xml, но всё тщетно.

Всё делалось по образцу, но почти всегда ошибка была в том, что при попытке создать отчёт появлялось предупреждение, что его создать не получится, так как директория allure-results не найдена или *Input directory should be not absolute for aggregate goal*.

Вот мой *pom.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ponamorev.testproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <allure.version>2.0-BETA20</allure.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <project.build.source>1.8</project.build.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${project.build.source}</target>
                    <source>${project.build.source}</source>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/target/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertiesFilePath>${basedir}/src/test/resources/allure.properties</propertiesFilePath>
                    <reportVersion>2.4.0</reportVersion>
                    <reportDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-report</reportDirectory>
                    <resultsDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                <propertiesFilePath>src/test/resources/allure.properties</propertiesFilePath>
                    <reportVersion>2.4.0</reportVersion>
                    <reportDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-report</reportDirectory>
                    <resultsDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

Выполнение тестов происходит командой **mvn clean test**
Попытки создать отчёт через различные команды: **mvn site**, **mvn allure:serve**, **mvn allure:report**
Скажите, где накосячил, глаза уже замылились, наверное, не могу понять никак.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас reportDirectory и reportDirectory однаковые. Нужно, чтобы один указывал на директорию конкретную, а второй содержал название папки

```
<plugin>         
   <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
   <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
       <resultsDirectory>allure-results</resultsDirectory>
       <reportDirectory>${basedir}/target/</reportDirectory>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

а в репортинг можно оставить только

```
<reporting>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</outputDirectory>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ)
Да, теперь папка allure-results создается, но отчёт пустой. Пытался сделать отчет через `mvn allure:serve`, `mvn allure:report` и `allure generate`. Все варианты безуспешны. Не знаете, как это исправить? Может, где-то что-то не указано?

Comment: возможно, из-за того, что нет `allure-report-builder`  в зависимостях

Comment: В allure 2 не нашёл такой зависимости..

Comment: я не уверен. [ссылка](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.allure/allure-report-builder/2.3)

Comment: Я поменял allure 2 на allure 1.  
Поставил `allure-junit-adaptor` версии 1.5.4, `allure-report-builder` версии 2.0. В секции `<reporting>` указал `allure-maven-plugin` версии 2.0. Для билдера и мавен плагина нет 1.5.4, там с 1.4.0 сразу на 2.0 идёт повышение версии.  
По-прежнему не создается папка `allure-results` :(

Comment: @VyacheslavP. пожалуйста, посмотрите внимательно на этот [pom](https://github.com/Tsovak/selenium-wrapper-framework/blob/master/pom.xml). оно рабочее

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло полное удаление секции `configuration` у плагина allure-maven.
Остался только путь в конфигурации `surefire: ${project.build.directory}/allure-results`

Проверьте, что в `target/allure-results` плагин surefire действительно кладет репорты после прогона тестов.

P.S. Запускаю из IDEA по clean test и allure:serve